# Making meat balls in chicken marinade

Tags: chicken, meatballs

I have this marinade in with I usually make chicken legs. It consists mainly of maple syrup, soy sauce, and sometimes ketchup.

Is it reasonable to put **meat** balls in that marinade? Is it OK to put them together with the chicken legs in the same pot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever marinade you like for meatballs, though I would personally find that way too sweet.

No you should not ever mix different raw meats together, unless they are being cooked and served together. That is called cross-contamination; contaminating one product with another.

Comment: How would you modify the marinade to better suit the meat balls?

Comment: I would go for slightly more savoury, omit the ketchup, add garlic and ginger and use hoisin instead of soy.